# Can compiler warn me if I forget to add an enum value to a map?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a situation similar to this:

```
enum E {
    Foo,
    Bar
}

const map = new Map<E, string>(
    [
        [E.Foo, "some data"],
        [E.Bar, "some other data"]
    ]
);
```

It's important to have all values of E in the map. Can that be ensured at compile-time? In other words, if a new value gets added to E, the compiler should yell at me: "Hey, you forgot add it to the map too!".

Motivation: E is generated from a type on the back-end, via a build step. When the back-end changes (i.e. adds a new enum value), we'd like to be aware of that on the front end as early as possible.

Comment: Create your own checker function which will iterate through all of your enum values and check the map for those as well. If one of them is missing make it so it throws an error or warns you in some other way.

Comment: @whatamidoingwithmylife Thanks for the suggestion but that's a run-time solution.

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you use a union type and `Record<>`, it'll throw an error if any value in the union is missing in the object

Comment: In fact, you can just use a Record instead of Map here and it'll throw an error if any value in the enum is not a key in the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @nullptr suggested, you should *probably* consider using a Record:

```
const record: Record<E, string> = {
    [E.Foo]: "some data",
    [E.Bar]: "some other data",
};
```

This will error if you duplicate a key, miss a key, or have an extraneous key. However, in the event that you cannot use a plain object and *must* use a map, then I propose the following:

```
const entries = [
    [E.Foo, "some data"],
    [E.Bar, "some other data"]
] as const;

type ExhaustiveCheck<T extends never = Exclude<E, typeof entries[number][0]>> = T;

const map = new Map<E, string>(entries);
```

We can take the fact that `Exclude` returns `never` when given two of the same type. That means if our entries were exhaustive, excluding the entries from `E` gives us `never`. If you forgot a key, the exhaustive check will provide an error (not the most helpful, but it should be enough info to deduce why it occured). If you have an extra key, you'll get an error when you try to create the map. So it's kinda like using a record... However, it does not protect against duplicate keys.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAolDeBYAUFNUBiB7LAaF6UAQgIYBOKAviigMZYgDOALlKM2QJbCNQC8UANoF0gmADpseKACJGWCMCgATEsxIyAuvlSiJpMrlnzFULMwAWwMirUbtKTVBK96TZgG4ayZgE8ADkowAB4WJGAsnABuwADCVrQA1gA8ACpswcygyrwgwDE2AiG0ADZgysDJMEZ+gVgAZmwgHNyMguAQAEbWmoIADJoAfIP8UKleyHQMLFAQJP6jeQDuUACy81VGLFwgAOaDABTsXDwAlBNT7lBkwPRkygBcUABKt1j3m1DbnHsjAki6NBiSQ4TRPOQKJSqdQyHSEYEGMHGSFmSzWWwwnSUDxAA)